# How to make the TFS Project Portal public?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to make the Team Project Portal of TFS public to everyone? Currently I get prompted for a user and password when I browse to the portal. For me this isn't a problem because I have a user, but I would like to use the link to a work item (a link like this: http://mytfsserver:8080/WorkItemTracking/WorkItem.aspx?artifactMoniker=xx) to send to a colleague who doesn't have a user.

Where can I change this if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware this isn't possible because the person viewing the portal needs to have a Client Access License.

You may be able to use the [Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892990.aspx) application to get around this.